# Coherent state path integral - derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, boundary-terms

I divided the time interval $[t_0=:t_i,t_f:=t_N]$ into $N$ steps $[t_{k-1},t_{k}],\, k=1,\dots, N$ and applied the resolution of unity for coherent states
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{I}=\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{dzd\bar{z}}{2\pi i}\exp\left\lbrace-z\bar{z}\right\rbrace\lvert z\rangle\langle z\rvert
\end{equation}
at each step; this yields the following 
\begin{multline}
   \langle{z_f}\lvert\left( \exp\lbrace-iH\epsilon\right\rbrace)^N\rvert z_i\rangle=\dots=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int\prod_{j=1}^{N-1}\frac{dz_jd\bar{z_j}}{2\pi i}\\
\exp\left\lbrace\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bar{z}_{k+1}z_k-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}z_k\bar{z_k}-i\epsilon\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}H(\bar{z}_{k+1},z_k)\right\rbrace,\quad(*)
\end{multline}
where $\epsilon:=\frac{t_f-t_i}{N}$, and with boundary conditions 
$z_0=z_i,\,\bar{z}_N=\bar{z}_f$.
Then I need to put $(*)$ in this form
\begin{align}
\int\mathcal{D}(z,\bar{z})&\exp\bigg\lbrace\frac{\bar{z}_fz_f+\bar{z}_iz_i}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\big[z_k(\bar{z}_{k+1}-\bar{z}_k)-\bar{z}_k(z_{k+1}-z_k)+\\
&-i\epsilon H(\bar{z}_{k+1},z_k)\big]\bigg\rbrace
\end{align}
but I can't understand how to transform the argument of the exponential.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**Source:** Itzykson - Zuber, page 438 with line 2 corrected as shown in the errata (you can find it here: http://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~zuber/corrize.pdf).

edit: @ ACuriousMind Then I don't understand how to rewrite it: is the following right?
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\big[z_k(\bar{z}_{k+1}-\bar{z}_k)-\bar{z}_k(z_{k+1}-z_k)\big]=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\big[z_k\bar{z}_{k+1}-\bar{z}_k z_{k+1}\big]=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\big[z_k\bar{z}_{k+1}\big]
\end{equation}
*if* this were right, I wouldn't know how to cope with this
\begin{equation}
-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}z_k\bar{z}_k
\end{equation}

If it is so straightforward to you, could you please rewrite it step-by-step?

Comment: It's just a rewriting of the sums, there's no "transformation" required.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210138/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic My doubt is not about the path integral itself... it's not obvious to me how to rewrite it in the symmetric form proposed by Itzykson - Zuber... Brown's form of coherent state path integral, which you cite, is slightly different, thus, it doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Hint: The sought-for manipulation of the action is a discrete version of changing $\lambda=0$ to $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ in eq. (7) in my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210184/2451).

Comment: You're right... but there is no derivation of that formula in your post. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222617/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643379/226902

Answer (score 1):

At last I think I managed to rearrange the terms in the sums... (which wasn't a monumental task after all ;-) )
\begin{equation}
   \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bar{z}_{k+1}z_k-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}z_k\bar{z}_k=(*)
\end{equation}
In the notation [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/210184/2451):

- $\lambda=0$: 
  \begin{equation}
  (*)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bar{z}_{k+1}z_k-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}z_{k+1}\bar{z}_{k+1}+z_N\bar{z}_N=-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bar{z}_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-z_k)+z_f\bar{z}_f,\,(1)
  \end{equation}
- $\lambda=1$:
  \begin{equation}
     (*)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bar{z}_{k+1}z_k-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}z_k\bar{z}_k+z_0\bar{z}_0=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}z_k(\bar{z}_{k+1}-\bar{z}_k)+z_i\bar{z}_i,\,(2)
  \end{equation}
  Taking $(2)+(1)$ we obtain $2(*)$, and finally
- $\lambda=1/2$
  \begin{equation}
     \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bar{z}_{k+1}z_k-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}z_k\bar{z}_k=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\big[z_k(\bar{z}_{k+1}-\bar{z}_k)-\bar{z}_{k+1}(z_{k+1}-z_k)\big]+\frac{z_i\bar{z}_i+z_f\bar{z}_f}{2}
  \end{equation}
  but there was a $+1$ missing in one of the $z$'s subscripts, if I'm right.